# How to use Script from Brownie Dependency

Tags: solidity, vyper, brownie

I have a brownie project containing the source code for a Vault contract as well as it's deployment script.

[Badger-Vaults](https://github.com/Badger-Finance/badger-vaults)
Containing the `Vault.vy` contract for vaults, as well as `scripts/deploy_badger_vault.py`

I'm working on a Brownie Mix: [Badger Vaults Mix V2](https://github.com/Badger-Finance/badger-vaults-brownie-mix-v2)

My goal is to import the script `scripts/deploy_badger_vault.py` and use it in the Brownie Mix.

Is there a way to import it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brownie doesn't have a functionality to import across brownie projects. So you have 2 options.

1. Copy paste the code
2. Pip install the repo and then use it in your code. See this [question for more information](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43261155/11969592).